# How to add a live counter in react that displays a firestore collection value securely?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

**Goal:** To have a live counter on my React Firebase site that displays the current number of views on my youtube channel.

**Method:** I am retrieving the view count by calling the Youtube API from a **firebase cloud function** so that I can protect my API key. Once I have the data, I use **another cloud function** to update a view count collection in my firestore database (using pubsub every 60 minutes). I then monitor this collection using onSnapshot in my front-end and display the value.

**Problem:** While this *does work,* I get an email every day from Firebase saying my firestore database "has insecure rules" because "any user can read the entire database." I do not want to add authentication to my site, but I would like to have the live counter fully secure. Does anybody know how to have a live counter referencing a firestore database?

**Front-end code:**

```
export default function Navbar() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState('');

  const unsub = onSnapshot(doc(db, "viewCount", "Count"), (doc) => {
    setCount(doc.get("View Count"));
  });
```

**Firestore rules:**

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if false; 
    }
  }
}
```

**Cloud functions**

```
/**
 * Function updates Firestore view count every 60 minutes
 * 
 * @param - 
 * @returns - N/A 
 */
exports.updateViewCount = functions.pubsub
  .schedule("every 60 minutes")
  .onRun((context) => {
    try {
      this.logCount(5);
      console.log("Count updated at:", new Date());
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error getting view count: ", error);
    }
  });



/**
 * Function calls getViewCount to get Youtube View Count
 * 
 * @param - 
 * @returns - Int: View count 
 */
exports.logCount = functions
  .runWith({
    secrets: ["YOUTUBE_API"],
  })
  .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const viewData = await getViewCount(
      process.env.YOUTUBE_API,
      process.env.YOUTUBE_CHANNEL_ID
    );
    const addData = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("viewCount")
      .doc("Count")
      .set({ "View Count": viewData })
      .then(() => {
        return viewData;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
      });
  });
```

**To recap:**

1. Is this the right way to implement a live counter with firestore without authentication?
2. If so: How can I do this more securely? If not: what other options are there?

Comment: Do you want ever random person who visits this website to be able to see the counter? Or should only you (and other people that you allow) be able to see it?

Comment: @NicholasTower I'd like everybody to be able to see the counter. I want it to be a part of the website, as if it were the time or weather being displayed.

Comment: K, then you just need to tweak your rules. I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 2):

To get the warning emails to stop, you just need to change your rules so that `allow read: if true;` isn't applied to the entire database. You can still apply it to the part of the database where the counter is.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /viewCount/Count {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if false; 
    }
  }
}
```

If you have other documents and collections that are being used by your app, you'll need to add rules for them too.